# What is wrong with this multiplication in Java: 27984*619246?

Tags: java

When I'm multiplying 27984 * 619246 it gives = `149110880` instead of `17328980064`! Can anyone Explain.

Comment: Ever heard of overflow?

Comment: What is the *type* you are storing these numbers in? Looks like you are using `int`

Comment: Use long, not integer.

Comment: had given -1 as datatypes details missing. also, no research efforts provided. P.S. sorry for late comment, i just started giving out comments on all my downvoted posts as it helps OP to understand concern ... as per contents from meta.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 7):

This is a case of an overflow happening

```
max int   ........... 2,147,483,647
your expected num .. 17,328,980,064
```

For things like this, you should use a `long`, which gives you 64 bits for storage instead of 32-bits like `int` does.

Answer (score 4):

You've got an overflow. Try to use another data type(Long for example)

Answer (score 3):

Probably you are using integers to multiply those numbers. The result of  multiplication you wish to perform is too large to store in an integer number (An int can only store 2^31 bits, or `21747483648`). You'll need another datatype: A long would be more appropriate here.

Comment: *2^31 digits* is wrong, you probably meant bits

Comment: MB, ment bits indeed =)